# Pegar string dentro de div em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável que armazena um bloco HTML:

```
$qtd = '<div id="itens">                
            <span>
                435 itens encontrados
            </span>
        </div>';
```

Eu preciso pegar o texto que está dentro dessa **div** e isso precisa acontecer no server-side...então qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isto utilizando o php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se trata de um pedaço de código HTML, você pode utilizar a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php):

```
$qtd = '<div id="itens">                
            <span>
                435 itens encontrados
            </span>
        </div>';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($qtd);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div");

echo $elements[0]->nodeValue;
```

Desta forma, o resultado do `echo` seria o conteúdo da `div`, incluindo a tag `span`, conforme descrito na pergunta. Mas caso o conteúdo desejado é o da `span`, basta trocar o nome da tag em:

```
$doc->getElementsByTagName("div");
// -------------------------^
```

Da seguinte forma:

```
$qtd = '<div id="itens"><span>435 itens encontrados</span></div>';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($qtd);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("span");

echo $elements[0]->nodeValue;
```

O resultado será:

```
435 itens encontrados
```

Comment: Muito bom! Eu vou me lembrar disso para sempre agora, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função strip_tags() juntamente com trim(), ela remove as tags de String Ex:

```
$out = trim(strip_tags($qtd));

var_dump($out);
```

A saída resultará em:

```
string(21) "435 itens encontrados"
```

Se quiser manter a tag span, pode fazer desta forma:

```
$out2 = trim(strip_tags($qtd, "<span>"));
```

Saída:

```
string(66) "<span>
            435 itens encontrados
           </span>"
```

Referência: [strip_tags php manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu testei aqui e também me serviu perfeitamente!